# $\mathbb{Q}^{alg}[[a,b]] $ is not elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{C}[[a,b]]$, and the same for $\mathbb{Q}^{alg}[a]$ and $\mathbb{C}[a]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, power-series, first-order-logic, model-theory

Since ACF is complete, $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}$ is elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$, and by Ax-Kochen $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}[[a]]$ is elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{C}[[a]]$.
But how should I show that $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}[[a,b]] $ is not elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{C}[[a,b]]$ and also $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}[a]$ is not elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{C}[a] $?

Comment: Did you really mean to ask about $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}[a]$ and $\mathbb{C}[a,b]$? Did you mean $\mathbb{C}[a]$?

Comment: Yes, thanks I didn't know how to write them...so sorry.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't complaining about the symbols (though I'm glad you've learned how to use \mathbb!). I was asking about the number of variables: [a] vs [a,b].

Comment: Oh! It was wrong! Edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My go-to reference for these kinds of questions is the book *Model Theoretic Algebra* by Jensen and Lenzing.

The question of how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}[a]$ and $\mathbb{C}[a]$ are not elementarily equivalent has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494419/elementary-equivalence-of-polynomial-rings) on this site. It is Example 3.12 in Jensen and Lenzing, and it is proceeded by a full proof, which I summarized in my answer to the linked question.

Remark 3.39 in Jensen and Lenzing states that $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}((x_1,\dots,x_n))$ and $\mathbb{C}((x_1,\dots,x_n))$ are not elementarily equivalent for any $n>1$. They do not prove this, but give a reference to the paper [Indécidabilité de la théorie des anneaux de séries formelles à plusieurs indéterminées](https://eudml.org/doc/211257) by Françoise Delon. The fact that $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}[[a,b]]$ and $\mathbb{C}[[a,b]]$ are not elementarily equivalent follows immediately, since the quotient fields $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{alg}}((a,b))$ and $\mathbb{C}((a,b))$ are interpretable in the power series rings.